# Renamed image does not appear in imageView

Tags: java, android

After renaming an image with this code:

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";
File from = new File (path, "old.jpg");
File to = new File (path, "new.jpg");
from.renameTo (to);
String newpath = to.getAbsolutePath();
```

If I try to open the gallery and select the same image (which has changed its name) this is not displayed in the imageView. Why?

Additional information: if I try to print the `URI` of the image while selecting it from the gallery it appears in the console:

```
D/picUri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/blablabla/ORIGINAL/NONE/2094062349
```

Comment: Bear in mind that changes that you make to the filesystem will take time to reflect in gallery apps, as those apps work off the of `MediaStore`. And, note that you will not be able to use your code on Android Q (by default) or Android R (for all apps), as we now have very restricted access to external storage.

Comment: How can I solve it? I must necessarily rename the image and then use it immediately

Comment: "I must necessarily rename the image" -- why? Why not save the image with the correct name in the first place?

Comment: Because the images are downloaded from the internet, I have to set the right name based on the style I want to give to the photo. If for example the user selects the Monet effect, the photo must become "monet.jpg" because it is processed in this way by the PHP server